# I accidentally bought an HDMI (male) to VGA (male) cable that isn't an adapter or converter of any sort. Does this product have any value?

Tags: cables, converter, adapter, vga, hdmi

I have a laptop with an HDMI port. I have a monitor with a VGA port. I wanted to connect the two. The website I bought this cable from labeled it as an 'adapter' so I assumed it would do the conversion job. Now the store tells me it's not a converter and that it is merely an 'adapter'.

I would really like to believe this isn't a scam and that I simply made a rookie mistake not checking this has an actual DIGITAL to ANALOG converter.

But I feel like this is a scam since I don't understand how this cable (or 'adapter') is a product.
To my understanding, if VGA could carry an HDMI signal or vice versa, then indeed this product would have value and it is an actual adapter and indeed this would be my mistake. But I understand that this is not possible.

So... In what scenario does this cable actually serve a purpose?

Comment: Where did you buy it?

Comment: eBay / AliExpress etc. sellers will sell cables with just about *any* combination of connectors on the ends, regardless of whether they will actually work.

Answer (score 3):

I've checked the product page of some of these "HDMI to VGA" adapter cables.

They mention "does not work with all HDMI sources, you must check if your PC or device supports it." This means the cable will only work if the PC video card, or whatever device has the HDMI output port implements circuitry to output analog VGA signals over the HDMI port when it detects it is plugged into a VGA port.

But they don't say what it is supposed to plug in. Since carrying VGA is NOT part of the HDMI standard, I'm not even sure how it is supposed to work or if manufacturers using this proprietary "extension" actually exits, or all agree on HDMI "analog" pinout about which VGA signal goes on which pin.

Quite suspicious IMO, wouldn't buy.

If your laptop doesn't have this extra feature (and I can't see why it would have it) then you need a real adapter with digital-to-analog conversion circuitry.

If the product description did not mention it, then this is a fault on the part of the seller and you should ask for a refund, or at least flag the product page for removal, or leave a review.

Comment: I have never heard of HDMI carrying analog video. DVI-I or DVI-A though. Can you link some?

Comment: Here's [one](http://vi.raptor.ebaydesc.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItemDescV4&item=283628632898&category=158840&pm=1&ds=0&t=1573079548000&ver=0) it's difficult to know how that works though. Description mentions "you will need a converter if your video card can't output 'digital signal over vga'" (the French description page is translated wrong, says the opposite of what it should, which screams 'dont buy' IMO)

Comment: That cable makes no sense at all.

Comment: Indeed it does not make any sense... I wonder what kind of hardware it's supposed to be compatible with . https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32830572041.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes at the supermarket you see all kinds of exotic cables that have no use and should not exist at all.

The only purpose of these cables may be to combine surplus stock into a product that can be sold to someone who buys it. If the buyer is a supermarket chain and they buy a ton of useless cables because they don't understand what they are buying, it's not the seller's fault really. I believe I once saw a cable with a DE-9 at one end, and DE-15 at the other end, looked like RS232-VGA cable.